# core data countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count: error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

i have this error when i add to core data new relationship. I read in internets many resources but they can`t help me... Maybe you can... 
This is my code then i adding relationship:

```
std = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Student" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
std.fio = fio.text;
std.phone = phone.text;
NSError *error;
self.selectedGroups = MSGTVC.selectedGroups;
for(Group *info in self.selectedGroups){
    [std addGroupsObject:info];
}    if (![self.context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Cant Save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);    }
```

in line [std addGroupsObject:info]; is error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Group countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x816a1c0'

This is my code then i assign value to selectedGroups:

```
   NSArray *indexselected = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows
__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_5_0)]]; 

    for (NSIndexPath *into in indexselected)
        {

            self.selectedGroups = [self.group objectAtIndex:into.row];

           }
```

I'll be happy if you help solve this problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: You're calling a for loop on something which is not an array (NSFastEnumeration). what type is self.selectedGroups

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *selectedGroups;

Comment: I figured out the problem, it was necessary to use NSMutableArray instead of NSArray and also not to forget to initialize it :)